# ClassCastException when try to use loaded class

Tags: java, reflection, casting

Java Version: 6

I have build an aotuloader which loads Classes out of a JAR and instances them. SO i get an ArrayList of all Instances which match to the specific path and Abstract Class.

```
package com.geNAZt.RegionShop.Util;

import com.geNAZt.RegionShop.RegionShopPlugin;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

public class Loader {
    public static <T> ArrayList<T> loadFromJAR(RegionShopPlugin plugin, String path, Class interf) {
        ArrayList<T> returnObjects = new ArrayList<T>();

        try {
            String pathToJar = Loader.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
            JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(pathToJar);
            Enumeration e = jarFile.entries();

            URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + pathToJar +"!/") };
            ClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                JarEntry je = (JarEntry) e.nextElement();

                if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class") || !je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6).replace("/", ".").contains(path +".")){
                    continue;
                }

                try {
                    String className = je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6);
                    className = className.replace('/', '.');
                    Class<?> c = cl.loadClass(className);

                    if(!c.getSuperclass().getName().equals(interf.getName())) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Constructor[] cons = c.getDeclaredConstructors();

                    for(Constructor con : cons) {
                        try {
                            returnObjects.add((T)con.newInstance(plugin));
                            break;
                        } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                            continue;
                        } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                            continue;
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                            continue;
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                } catch(ClassNotFoundException er) {
                    er.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                }

            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }

        return returnObjects;
    }
}
```

It works fine an i get the right Objects with:

```
private ArrayList<ShopCommand> loadedCommands = new ArrayList<ShopCommand>();
loadedCommands = loadFromJAR(pl, "com.geNAZt.RegionShop.Command.Shop", ShopCommand.class);
```

If i make a log all Objects seem to be fine:

> 12:24:40 [INFO] [RegionShop] Loaded ShopCommands: [com.geNAZt.RegionShop.Command.Shop.ShopAdd@3b39c41d, com.geNAZt.RegionShop.Command.Shop.ShopBuy@4d7a6a4b, com.geNAZt.RegionS
>   hop.Command.Shop.ShopDetail@1fd889aa, com.geNAZt.RegionShop.Command.Shop.ShopEquip@4136083b, com.geNAZt.RegionShop.Command.Shop.ShopList@42567aef, com.geNAZt.RegionShop.Comman
>   d.Shop.ShopName@3ba102ef]

But then i want to use them. In case to use them i wanted to cast them into the ShopCommand Class. But then i get this error:

> 12:24:40 [SCHWERWIEGEND] Error occurred while enabling RegionShop v1.1.0b3 (Is it up to date?)
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.geNAZt.RegionShop.Command.Shop.ShopAdd cannot be cast to com.geNAZt.RegionShop.Command.ShopCommand
>           at com.geNAZt.RegionShop.Command.ShopExecutor.(ShopExecutor.java:40)
>           at com.geNAZt.RegionShop.RegionShopPlugin.onEnable(RegionShopPlugin.java:80)
>           at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:217)
>           at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:457)
>           at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:383)
>           at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:305)
>           at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:287)
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R3.MinecraftServer.j(MinecraftServer.java:310)
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R3.MinecraftServer.e(MinecraftServer.java:289)
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:249)
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:152)
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:388)
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R3.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:573)

Is it possible to cast the Objects into the abstract class so i get the api from the Class ? Or is there another way to get the API from the Class ?

Comment: Quick question: Java 6 or 7? If 7 you can use `FileSystems.newFileSystem()` to create a filesystem to your jar directly

Comment: Java 6. But the problem is not within the loading of the objects. I cant cast them, thats the problem.

Comment: Why don't you use `.isAssignableFrom()` on your `interf` parameter to check whether your class is "good"?

Comment: Because it always says that my class i not good. I dont know why it does that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is the result of *class identity crisis* . You cannot cast between class loaders. As mentioned [this site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0429/):

> Other types of confusion are also possible when using multiple class
>   loaders. Figure 2 shows an example of a class identity crisis that
>   results when an interface and associated implementation are each
>   loaded by two separate class loaders. *Even though the names and binary
>   implementations of the interfaces and classes are the same, an
>   instance of the class from one loader cannot be recognized as
>   implementing the interface from the other loader*.

**EDIT**
Although the solution is found out by the OP but I would like to give my [two cents](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two_cents#Noun).
The confusion which is leading to the nonrecognition of instance of the class from other `ClassLoader` could easily be resolved if that class is *moved into the System class loader's space*. And making `System Class Loader` to be the parent of newly created `ClassLoader`s. This would cause the different `ClassLoader`s to share the same class. This could be achieved by [`URLClassLoader(URL[] urls,ClassLoader parent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#URLClassLoader%28java.net.URL%5B%5D,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) in following way:

```
URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + pathToJar +"!/") };
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls,ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

Comment: And how can i be safe that both the abstract class and the object came out of the same ClassLoader ?

Comment: I found the solution. i changed 

ClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

to

ClassLoader cl = Loader.class.getClassLoader();

and everything works fine. Now i also can get rid of the getSuperClass thing. Thanks